# Sound works in Ubuntu but not in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card

I tried updating device drivers in windows, but it just says "no headphones or speakers plugged in."

It was working on the same hardware with windows 10 running on it previously. I had a disk failure and had to replace the hard disk and re install windows 10. Sound has not worked since then.

Also running the trouble shooter says "Audio services not responding."

> Both the Windows Audio and the Windows Audio End Point Builder services must be running for audio to work correctly. At least one of these services isn't responding.

but both services are shown as running in Services and in Task Manager. The Realtek HD Audio driver and codecs are installed, and I've gone through the various sound menu items.

Comment: do you have the Realtek HD Audio driver and codecs (or AC'97 codecs for old systems) installed?

Comment: Yes realtek HD audio driver is installed

Comment: @AkashGarule Go to the speaker icon in the traybox, click it and choose the output correct device. Might be a missmatch between Realtek and windows 10 sound options. Happened something similar to me, after my doggo stomped the keyboard my pc went silent. Fiddle for an hour or so on those menus to get everything back to as it was.

Comment: @dmb already tried all of that. doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. plug in a head phone and check... I had same problem it worked;
2. remove all sound drivers and then download a driver from the website of the sound card company.